# Runaway jQuery - Page runs slower over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, cufon

We have a timer that removes the top item in an unordered list and moves it to the bottom of the list. Each item has images, custom fonts, rollovers, etc.

For some reason, the longer the page runs, the slower it gets. You can notice the latency when hovering over the ribbons. The ribbons are supposed to turn red on hover, but when it slows down you'll notice it can take several seconds to see the hover state.

I have no idea why this is happening. I believe we're properly cleaning everything up, but something is obviously wrong.

Here's the page in question...
http://gmfg.trailerparkinteractive.com/

Let me know if I can provide any additional detail.

Comment: On an unrelated note: JPEG compression. Look into it.

Comment: works for me, i cant say i like the moving of a page its a UI annoyance!

Comment: Found the issue! We were calling Cufon.Replace on every interval. Even though we used the same selector, it seems that Cufon added these to it's collection. This caused cufon to run slower and slower over time.

THanks

Comment: @Blazemonger - we'll optimize the images

Comment: @JonH - I'm only implementing the UI, but I kindof like the motion.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you have a memory leak and [here's how you detect one](http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/08/finding-memory-leaks.html).

It seems one of your scripts is allocating and deallocating a lot of memory over a short period of time.

[image: memory leak]

Further drilling into the retaining tree we find that some HTML element nodes are being deleted from the DOM but not released.

[image: retention tree]

My advice is, try running your site while disabling different scripts, and retest with this method to get a guestimate of which plugin is doing that.